# python simplest ICMP ping

Tags: python, python-2.7, ping

How do I check if a device (phone) is connected to a home WIFI or not. I'd like to monitor LAN and run specific function once phone connects and continue monitoring when it disconnects.

I'd like to ping and get a boolean response if it reaches its destination. I've tried `ping.verbose_ping('192.168.1.x', count=1)` but it just prints in console and I don't get anything in my script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `ping.do_one`

```
ping.do_one('www.q.com', 1, 1)
```

you'll get a None

```
ping.do_one('localhost', 1, 1)
```

you'll get a round trip time

```
ping.do_one('unknown_host', 1, 1)
```

you'll get an exception

Answer (score 0):

Scapy is your friend ;)

```
import scapy
from scapy.all import *
def ping(host, count=1):
  packet = IP(dst=host)/ICMP()
  for x in range(count):
     ans = sr1(packet)
     ans.show2()

ping ("192.168.1.x",your_count_value)
```